# Samba unstable, goes to 100% CPU

Tags: linux, ubuntu, samba

We have upgraded Ubuntu to 16.04 and SAMBA become unstable on the same server. On high usage SAMBA use all CPU resources and stops working, never had problems before and usage didn't increased.

Issues are exact the same as described here:
http://samba.2283325.n4.nabble.com/Many-quot-smbd-quot-process-with-quot-D-quot-uninterruptible-sleep-status-td4655201.html

4.4.0-139-generic #165-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 24 10:58:50 UTC 2018 x86_64
x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Any ideas what could cause the problem and how to troubleshoot and solve the problem?